# Image not displaying on the page

Tags: html, css

The image is not displaying on the page when I am using the image in my CSS code. I have used couple of CSS Tricks but the image is not displaying on the page

```css
.header-image {
  background-image: url('img/billboard.jpg');
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 400px) {
  .header-image {
    background-image: url(../img/billboard.jpg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="header-image">
  <div class="bottom-left"></div>
  <div class="top-left container">
    <img src="img/icon.png" height="48px" width="98px">
    <p class="f-s-7">EXPERIENCE EXCELLENCE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="top-right">
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cl-black" id="text-decorate-none">CAREERS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cl-black" id="text-decorate-none">CLIENT LOGIN</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cl-black" id="text-decorate-none">CONTACT US</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/social-icons/linkedin.png" class="social"></li>
      <li><img src="img/social-icons/facebook.png" class="social"></li>
      <li><img src="img/social-icons/twitter.png" class="social"></li>
      <li><img src="img/social-icons/instagram.png" class="social"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><a href="#" class="cl-black" id="text-decorate-none">WHY WAVEX</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cl-black" id="text-decorate-none">MANAGED IT SERVICES</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cl-black" id="text-decorate-none">SECURITY SERVICES</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cl-black" id="text-decorate-none">CLOUD SECVICES</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cl-black" id="text-decorate-none">PROJECTS & IT SOLUTIONS</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#" class="cl-black" id="text-decorate-none">BUSINESS STRATEGY</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>
```

Using `<img>` tag inside the div is displaying the image but, in CSS it is not displaying.
The CSS code which I have used are:

```
background-image: url(../img/billboard.jpg);
background-image: url('../img/billboard.jpg');
background-image: url(img/billboard.jpg);
background-image: url('/img/billboard.jpg');
```

None of the above code worked. Kindly Help!!

Comment: have you tried `background-image: url("img/billboard.jpg");` ?

Comment: Inspect the element front end with your browser's inspector to see where the image is trying to get called from, it should help you pin down the issue.

Comment: A sidenote: You are using the ID `text-decorate-none` on 9 elements, which is invalid HTML - IDs have to be unique. Use another class instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is answered, ad nauseum, both here on SO and all over the internet with the exact same solution every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have taken wrong path for your background-image. try to set it right. hope will fix your issue.

```
<style>
    .header-image {
        background-image: url('./img/billboard.jpg');
    }

    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 400px) {
        .header-image {
            background-image: url(./img/billboard.jpg);
        }
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have referenced your .css file incorrectly.
Shouldn't it be link

```
rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your folder structure is as follows:

```
|-root/
|--css/
|   |--style.css
|--img/
|   |--billboard.jpg
|--index.html
```

And you're calling the image from `style.css`, your css would look like this

```
.header-image {
  background-image: url('../img/billboard.jpg');
}
```

If you're calling from `index.html`, your css would look like this:

`.header-image {
  background-image: url('img/billboard.jpg');
}`

And you will need `height` and `width` so that the image can show up.

Answer (score 0):

first put your image behind html file and try

```
 background-image: url("yourimage.jpg");
```

if it's work and you see image then copy image in folder and use ./ or main address for that .

in w3schools website for url in background-image use " not ' .

Answer (score 0):

Please put all external resources in head tag.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

In addition you should not set width or height as pixels in img attribute. Instead, try this way below

`<img src="img/icon.png" height="48" width="98">`

One more thing you should pay attention is that, if you want to use internal css, you should write your rules in head tag.

```
<head>
    <style>
    ...
    </style>
</head>
```